# Print/highlight/export all checked checkbox using Chrome Dev Tools (or other)

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a page which is used for keeping track of a collection by using check boxes.
The site provides no ability to export the checked items or view them in a consolidated view - you must scan over hundreds (thousands?) of boxes to see just the ones you've checked.

I'm looking for a way using Chrome Dev Tools (or other plugin/extension/etc), to somehow print a list, export, and/or highlight only the checked elements on the page to make it easy to view them all.

Thoughts?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Its not hard to get an array of checked checkbox elements, but I have a feeling that would help much?

Comment: Any options that would be easy to provide.  The site in question is:

https://mini.ixbyix.com/

I would like to easily be able to export all the checked box data into a list.  Barring that, even somehow highlighting or color-coding the text element of the checkbox to make it easier to see.

Comment: There's no such feature in devtools. Other than writing your own js code to tackle this, try looking into extensions that process forms like roboform or lastpass, there could be many others, try using google search.

Comment: AFAIK, Dev Tools allows you to run a piece of JS code against the form...so this is what I am asking - if someone can provide a snippet that might do the job.  I researched a way to do this prior to my post and was unable to find a way.  I'm not sure how a password processing tool will help in this case.